# samba denied access

Tags: networking, server, permissions, samba

I have a samba server with the following configuration:

```
[SDK]
        comment = SDK of Kallel
        path = /home/user/smbtest
        public = no
        writable = yes
        browseable = yes
        valid users = root
```

the permission of `/home/user/smbtest` is 777

I can access to the samba server from another PC. But when I try to execute ls on the samba server, it return access denied error:

```
$  /usr/bin/smbclient \\\\192.168.103.3\\sdk -U root root
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Domain=[MYGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.2.11-0.28.fc9]
smb: \> ls
NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED listing \*
smb: \>
```

Am I missing something in my samba config ?

Answer (score 0):

Disable SELinux in `/etc/selinux/config` and then reboot.